# How to add local file link to Exported CSV file using C#

Tags: c#, excel, csv, export

I want to add the link to my local file into one of the columns of Exported CSV file.So that when user clicks on the link the local file open. I have searched the internet for this but can't find any good solution.

Here is the screenshot of what i try to do -

[image]

Suppose when user clicks on File path selected row file full name then upon click i should open the file at that localtion.

My code to generate the CSV file is-

```
    public void GetExportDetailsCSV(ExportInformation ExportInfo)
    {
        StringBuilder cameraRows = new StringBuilder();
        string filePath = ExportInfo.ExportOutputPathAtClient + SLASH_STRING + "ExportDetails.csv";
        string columnsNames = "File Name ,File Path" + "\r\n";

        if(Directory.Exists(ExportInfo.ExportOutputPathAtClient))
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(string.Format("{0}{1}", ExportInfo.ExportOutputPathAtClient, SLASH_STRING), "*" + ExportInfo.VideoFileFormat.ToString(), SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    FileInfo FileDetails = new FileInfo(newPath);
                    cameraRows.Append(string.Format("{0},{1}\r\n", FileDetails.Name, FileDetails.FullName));
                }

                string FinalData = "\nExport Remarks : Simple Export " + "\n\n" + "," + "," + "," + "," + "File Details" + "," + "\r\n" + "\r\n" + columnsNames + "\n " + cameraRows;
                using (var stream = System.IO.File.CreateText(filePath))
                {
                    stream.WriteLine(FinalData);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }                                
        }            
    }
```

My question is simple how can i put file location value as a link in my Exported CSV file.
Thankyou!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the Hyperlink function. Check this [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/hyperlink-function-333c7ce6-c5ae-4164-9c47-7de9b76f577f)

You can try this sample. Open notepad type below the line and save it as CSV.

```js
This,is,demo,"=HYPERLINK(""http://www.google.com/"",""Link"")"
```

Hopefully, this will solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, it will. Read the documentation link.